# How to conform to protocol using subclass

Tags: swift, class, protocols, subclass

Say I have a protocol

```
protocol A: class {
  func configure(view: UIView)
}
```

Now I want to conform to this protocol, using `UILabel` as a subclass of `UIView`

```
final class B: A {
  init() {}

  func configure(view: UILabel) {

  }
}
```

But errors

> Type B does not conform to protocol A

It seems that Swift needs exactly the same type as stated in the protocol. This works

```
final class B: A {
  init() {}

  func configure(view: UIView) {

  }
}
```

But I want to use `UILabel`, How to work around this?

Comment: Why can't the protocol's configure method expect a `UILabel` instead of a `UIView` if that's not what you want to pass it?

Comment: Say you create an instance of your class B. Now let's say you upcast it to your protocol type A. Now you have an instance that appears to be able to accept any `UIView` as an argument to your given method, when in fact it only deals specifically with `UILabels` – which is why this code cannot compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an `associatedType` that is constrained to be of type `UIView`.

```
protocol A: class {
    associatedtype View: UIView
    func configure(view: View)
}
```

Now in class `B`, since `UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView`, it's fine to do:

```
final class B: A {
    init() {}

    func configure(view: UILabel) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help!